# Can't capture the fields of a firestore document with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I queried for a specific field from Firestore document in React but I can't seem to capture the value itself as a string. Every time I console.log, I get a promise back, but I'm not sure how to isolate the string returned from that promise. Code and the database are below.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { firestore } from '../../firebase/firebase.utils';

const name = firestore.collection('blog-categories').doc('8uVaHd22tT5oXSzpOOuj').get().then(doc => 
doc.get('name'));

class Economics extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: name
    }
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.name);
    return (
      <div>
        {/* { this.state.name } */ }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Economics;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Getting document from firestore is an asynchronous operation. When you set name in the constructor the promise hasn't been resolved and also you're passing the promise directly instead of passing the value that has been resolved.
Instead you can call the promise in componentdidmount and you can set the value using setstate.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { firestore } from '../../firebase/firebase.utils';

class Economics extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
    name: ''
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    firestore.collection('blog-categories').doc('8uVaHd22tT5oXSzpOOuj').get().then(doc => {
    this.setState({ name: doc.get('name') });
    });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.name);
    return (
    <div>
        {/* { this.state.name } */ }
    </div>
    )
}
}

export default Economics;
```